# how to print a table for a pandas data frame in Pyscripter?

Tags: python, pandas, pyscripter

Is there a way to show a pandas data frame in Pyscripter in a table form? Sure a data frame shows up on the python interface, but i could not find an option to print it in a more graphical , eye-friendly table form... Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL to wrangle your data for you tabular analysis.

**Visit** https://mode.com/example-gallery/python_dataframe_styling/

It's a great place to learn dataframe styling.